# Access 2010 : Allow combox box search, but lock for edit

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm just reacquainting myself with Access after a long absence and am getting hung up on some relatively minor things !!

I have a form designed so users can select a ReportID from a combo box and the other fields in the form populates the information. That works great, however I don't want users to be able to update the fields, it's for reference only.

If I lock the form for editing then the combo box select doesn't work - is there a way that I can have a combo box control a form, but not allow editing or updating of any other returned fields ?

Answer (score 1):

Set the fields Locked property to Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change two properties of Combo Box under Data tab Under properties. Following are the properties to be changed:

1. "Limit To List" the default value for "Limit To List" is "No" change this to "Yes"
2. "Allow Value List Edits" the default value for "Allow Value List Edits" is "Yes" change this to "No"

After doing this modifications on the default values the user will be allowed to modify the text in the Combo Box, but when the user is leaving the Combo Box the BeforeUpdate event will be fired and the user will get an exclamation message from MS Access.

See the below given pictures for more clarity. The first picture shows the default values, second picture shows changed values and the third picture shows the message if values are edited.

Default Value [1]
![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxUUa.png

Change To [2]
![2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLnSM.png

Message from MS Access [3]
![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbPmc.png

**

### Kindly reply to this message if this solves your problem.

**

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure your combobox is unbound (not linked to a field by its ControlSource property)
- position it in the form header (not the Detail section)
- set the form's Filter property to the combobox using the expression builder (button with '...')
- also set the form's FilterOn property to true

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194672%28v=office.14%29.aspx